Having errors while running npm i in react project
npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm error
npm error While resolving: react-iframe-click@2.0.2
npm error Found: react@18.2.0
npm error node_modules/react
npm error   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm error   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.11.4
npm error   node_modules/@emotion/react
npm error     @emotion/react@"^11.8.1" from react-select@5.8.0
npm error     node_modules/react-select
npm error       react-select@"^5.7.4" from the root project
npm error   10 more (@emotion/use-insertion-effect-with-fallbacks, ...)
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer react@"^16.8.0" from react-iframe-click@2.0.2
npm error node_modules/react-iframe-click
npm error   react-iframe-click@"^2.0.2" from the root project
npm error
npm error Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm error node_modules/react
npm error   peer react@"^16.8.0" from react-iframe-click@2.0.2
npm error   node_modules/react-iframe-click
npm error     react-iframe-click@"^2.0.2" from the root project
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm error
npm error
npm error For a full report see:
npm error C:\Users\AdnanArif\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-08-02T09_46_28_846Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\AdnanArif\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-08-02T09_46_28_846Z-debug-0.log

I have tried many ways, We can cheat via --peer-deps, but that will not work in production.

Did you delete node_modules between tries? Did it work previously? If so, which versions worked?

Try to use yarn instead of npm. hopefully it should resolve your issue

The react-iframe-click version is incompatible with your reactjs version, so it shows you a dependency error. can you show post the package?json file from your project so that I can answer more correctly.
